# How to use undetermined coefficients to solve an equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For this question, I'm having trouble solving this equation. Here is what I have so far. Can anyone please help me out?

$$u'' + u' + 2u = \sin^2t$$

$$ u'' + u' + 2u = 0$$

$$ m^2 + m + 2 = 0$$

$$ m = \frac{-1 +- \sqrt{1-4(1)(2)}}{2}$$

$$ m = \frac{-1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{7}{i}}{2}$$

$$ u = e^\frac{-t}{2}(c_1\cos\sqrt{7}t + c_2\sin\sqrt{7}t)$$

Comment: You still need a particular solution.

Comment: How would I proceed further?

Answer (score 1):

For the complementary solution it should be

$$u_c(t)=e^{-\frac{t}{2}}\big((c_1\cos\big(\frac{\sqrt{7}}{\color\red{2}}t\big)+c_2\sin\big(\frac{\sqrt{7}}{\color\red{2}}t\big)\big)$$

Then using the identity $\cos(2t)=1-2\sin^2(t)$ we have  $$u''+u'+2u=\sin^2(t)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\cos(2t)}{2}$$ So for the particular integral try $u_{p}(t)=A\cos(2t)+B\sin(2t)+C.$

> You should get $$u(t)=e^{-\frac{t}{2}}\big((c_1\cos\big(\frac{\sqrt{7}}{\color\red{2}}t\big)+c_2\sin\big(\frac{\sqrt{7}}{\color\red{2}}t\big)\big)+\frac{1}{8}\big(\cos(2t)-\sin(2t)\big) +\frac{1}{4}.$$

---

We have $$u_{p}=A\cos(2t)+B\sin(2t)+C$$
$$u_{p}'=-2A\sin(2t)+2B\cos(2t)$$
$$u_{p}''=-4A\cos(2t)-4B\sin(2t)$$

Substituting, we obtain

$$u_{p}''+u_{p}'+2u_{p}=-4A\cos(2t)-4B\sin(2t)$$
$$-2A\sin(2t)+2B\cos(2t)$$
$$+2A\cos(2t)+2B\sin(2t)+2C$$
$$=-2A\cos(2t)-2B\sin(2t)+2B\cos(2t)-2A\sin(2t)+2C$$
$$=(-2A+2B)\cos(2t)-(2A+2B)\sin(2t)+2C=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\cos(2t)$$

And comparing coefficients we have $$-2A+2B=-\frac{1}{2}$$
$$2A+2B=0$$
$$2C=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\implies A=\frac{1}{8}, \space B=-\frac{1}{8}, \space C=\frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: So I get $-2Acos(2t)-4Bsin(2t)-2Asin(2t)+4Bcos(2t)=sin^2t$ after  I substitute into the equation, so how do I isolate for A and B now?

Comment: @user6789 I've added above, you compare coefficients with the RHS.

Answer (score 0):

Use Euler's formula to express $\sin^2(t)$ in terms of exponentials

$$\sin^2(t) = -\frac 14 (e^{2it} -2 + e^{-2it}) $$

now try a solution of the form $Ae^{2it} + B + C e^{-2it}$